# Error de sintaxis en sentencia Update Java

Tags: java, update

Estoy intentando hacer un `update` a la `bbdd` pero tengo error de sintaxis en el la linea de la sentencia sql:

```
  String sql = "update vehiculo set Modelo = '" + leer.nextLine() + "' where modelo = '" + modelo "'";
```

Mensaje de error:

> "; expected".

Gracias de antemano.

```
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Vamos a modificar el modelo de un vehiculo.");
    System.out.println("¿Que modelo quieres cambiar?");
    String modelo = leer.nextLine();
    String sql = "update vehiculo set Modelo = '" + leer.nextLine() + "' where modelo = '" + modelo "'";
    Statement stat = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stat.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: `String sql = "update vehiculo set Modelo = '" + leer.nextLine(); + "' where modelo = '" + modelo "'";` A `leer.nextLine()` le falta el `;` . Prueba a poner el punto y coma

Comment: @MarioGuiber , el ; que le protesta me pareces que es el de dentro del sql. Si pone un ; en el medio de su instruccion le va a dar un error peor.

Comment: He probado a ponerlo pero me pone: not a statement ; expected bad operand type string for unary operator +

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón! Ahora que me fijo más detenidamente es correcto lo que dices.

Comment: Te falta un ; dentro de la sentencia sql. cambia + modelo "'"; por + modelo "';";... Olvidate de lo que dijo mario (el ya se dio cuenta)

Comment: Ahora esta asi! "update vehiculo set Modelo = '" + leer.nextLine() + "' where modelo = '" + modelo "';"; Pero aun me aparece el mismo error: ; expected

Answer (score 1):

Falta concatenar la última parte del String:

```
  String sql = "update vehiculo set Modelo = '" + 
  leer.nextLine() + 
  "' where modelo = '" + 
   modelo+ //Falta esta concatención
   "'";
```